# Interchange Union/Intersection with minus sign (Identity)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$$C − (B \cup A) = (C − B) − A$$

I've to solve these kinda question, one identity that I know is

---

### $$A-B = A\cap B'$$

How can we replace $A\cup B$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using De Morgan's law,

$$C-(B \cup A)=C \cap (B \cup A)'=C\cap B'\cap A'$$